# Non-standard sorting algorithm for random unique integers

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of at least 2000 random unique integers, each in range 0 < n < 65000.

I have to sort it and then get the index of a random value in the array. Each of these operations have to be as fast as possible. For searching the binary-search seems to serve well.

For sorting I used the standard quick sorting algorithm (qsort), but I was told that with the given information the standard sorting algorithms will not be the most efficient. So the question is simple - what would be the most efficient way to sort the array, with the given information? Totally puzzled by this.

Comment: Try searching the web: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Efficient_sorts

Comment: Will you be using the array for more than finding the index of a certain value? If not, you could just loop through all the numbers and see how many values are less than your value which would be the index with no need to sort...?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews By non-standard I figured there could be some kind of an implementation to suit exactly the given parameters. You're right about the fact that non-standard could also imply to one certain implementation of for example distribution sort (e.g. counting/bucket/radix).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The goal for sorting is for the array to be sorted. Getting the index of a random value is basically a separate task. Sorry if this was unclear.

Comment: Why do you want to solve this problem? I would expect qsort to be fast enough for any practical application of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quicksort's complexity is `O(n*log(n))`, where `n = 2000` in your case. `log(2000) = 10.965784`.

You can sort in `O(n)` using one of these algorithms:

- [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)
- [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)
- [Bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)

I've compared `std::sort()` to counting sort for `N = 100000000`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void countSort(int t[], int o[], int c[], int n, int k) 
{
    // Count the number of each number in t[] and place that value into c[].
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        c[t[i]]++;
    // Place the number of elements less than each value at i into c[].  
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        c[i] += c[i - 1];
    // Place each element of t[] into its correct sorted position in the output o[].
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        o[c[t[i]] - 1] = t[i];
        --c[t[i]];
    }
}

void init(int t[], int n, int max)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        t[i] = rand() % max;
}

double getSeconds(clock_t start)
{
    return (double) (clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

void print(int t[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << t[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 100000000;
    const int MAX = 65000;
    int *t = new int[N];

    init(t, N, MAX);
    //print(t, N);
    clock_t start = clock();
    sort(t, t + N);  
    cout << "std::sort " << getSeconds(start) << endl;
    //print(t, N);

    init(t, N, MAX);
    //print(t, N);
    // o[] holds the sorted output.
    int *o = new int[N];
    // c[] holds counters.
    int *c = new int[MAX + 1];
    // Set counters to zero.
    memset(c, 0, (MAX + 1) * sizeof(*c));
    start = clock();
    countSort(t, o, c, N, MAX);
    cout << "countSort " << getSeconds(start) << endl;
    //print(o, N);

    delete[] t;
    delete[] o;
    delete[] c;
    return 0;
}
```

Results (in seconds):

```
std::sort 28.6
countSort 10.97
```

For `N = 2000` both algorithms give `0` time.

Comment: @Downvoter: Could you please comment what's wrong with my answer? Maybe I can make it better.

Comment: That example makes no sense.  Why are you using malloc and free?  Why are you including the memory allocations within the sorting function?  std::sort certainly doesn't allocate memory during a sort, therefore the comparison is invalid in my opinion.  Then of course, there is a major bug that blast furnace pointed out.  The timing numbers make no sense.

Comment: I tried running it with the correction, but the output of the countsort did not look like it was actually sorted.  Even when running in debug mode with visual studio 2010 my numbers were also significantly different (6.139, 1.789).

Comment: Oh I see.  There is still another bug when copying into arrayA near the end of the sorting function.  That is probably why the output didn't look sorted to me.

Comment: @shawn1874 You're right, I've used a code found on the internet, which turned out to have pretty low quality. I've updated the answer with mine implementation of counting sort, which (I hope) is better :)

Comment: I get an access violation on this line o[c[t[i]] - 1] = t[i]; I'm running with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: somehow, c[t[i]] = 505285904 but I'm not sure how it is possible.  Debugging that seemed like an interesting thing to do, but I'm out of time.  Since I can't get either to run without crashing or producing unexpected results, I cannot trust this algorithm.

Comment: @shawn1874 Counting sort works for sure. Maybe there is a problem with environment (or with my implementation, but I don't see any bug now). With VC you can try to run in release or in debug mode, see if there is any difference. Also, for `N = 100000000` make sure you don't have too low heap size limit.

Comment: `sizeof c` when `c` is a pointer gives you the size of a pointer (4 or 8 bytes, typically).

Comment: @shawn1874 That line with `sizeof` was probably causing problems, you can try the code now.

Comment: Thanks very much @AdamStelmaszczyk, you showed me the right direction - I implemented my own counting sort and VOILA! it was a lot faster than any of std::sort, qsort etc. tyvm!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why the person who told you that would be so peversely cryptic, but indeed `qsort` is not the most efficient way to sort integers (or generally anything) in C++. Use `std::sort` instead.

It's *possible* that you can improve on your implementation's `std::sort` for the stated special case (2000 distinct random integers in the range 0-65k), but you're unlikely to do a lot better and it almost certainly won't be worth the effort. The things I can think of that might help:

- use a quicksort, but with a different pivot selection or a different threshold for switching to insertion sort from what your implementation of `sort` uses. This is basically tinkering.
- use a parallel sort of some kind. 2000 elements is so small that I *suspect* the time to create additional threads will immediately kill any hope of a performance improvement. But if you're doing a lot of sorts then you can average the cost of creating the threads across all of them, and only worry about the overhead of thread synchronization rather than thread creation.

That said, if you generate and sort the array, then look up just *one* value in it, and then generate a new array, you would be wasting effort by sorting the whole array each time. You can just run across the array counting the number of values smaller than your target value: this count is the index it would have. Use `std::count_if` or a short loop.

> Each of these operations have to be as fast as possible.

That is not a legitimate software engineering criterion. Almost anything can be made a minuscule bit faster with enough months or years of engineering effort -- nothing complex is ever "as fast as possible", and even if it was you wouldn't be able to prove that it cannot be faster, and even if you could there would be new hardware out there somewhere or soon to be invented for which the fastest solution is different and better. Unless you intend to spend your whole life on this task and ultimately fail, get a more realistic goal ;-)

Comment: You make a good case. The problem itself is not actually tied to anything practical - it is just a programming challenge. The sorting and searching are 2 separate tasks. I am just trying to find out if there are some unorthodox implementations of some algorithm which would give a noticable improvement over standard quicksort.

Comment: OK, I'll add a bit about what *might* be better.

Comment: fyi, counting sort gave me a noticable improvement.

Comment: @Reins: I'm surprised, because like vhallac's answer I'd expect that just zeroing out the memory for 65k counts would already take a significant chunk of the time you'd spend sorting 2k values. So in effect my intuition that 2k is a small number, was wrong.

Comment: I was as surprised as you. :D

Comment: I can't reproduce it btw. On gcc with -O3 my counting sort is 50% slower than `std::sort`.

Comment: Before you ask: `std::uint16_t counts[0x10000] = {}; for (auto val : data) { counts[val] = 1; }; std::uint16_t *ptr = result; for (int i = 0; i < 0x10000; ++i) { if (counts[i]) *(ptr++) = i; }`. I actually didn't bother generating data with no duplicates, so the counting sort even has an unfair advantage that it doesn't need to write the full 2000 output values...

Comment: Ahem, spot the error. Changing the type of `counts` to `char` speeds things up a bit. Now only 8.7 vs 6.0, was 9.1 vs 6.0

Comment: btw, my question was phrased "...at least 2000..." - meaning that the size could be anywhere between 2000 and 65000. While I have to agree that with 2k elements the differences are insignificant, with for example 30k elements std::sort take 17 ms and counting sort 3 ms on my computer. Your help is still much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For sorting uniformly distributed random integers [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)  is typically the fastest algorithm, it can be faster than quicksort by a factor of 2 or more.  However, it may be hard to find an optimized implementation of that, quick sort is much more ubiquitous.  Both Radix Sort and Quick Sort may have very bad worst case performance, like O(N^2), so if worst case performance is important you have to look elsewhere, maybe you pick [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), which is similar to std::sort in C++.

For array look up a hash table is by far the fasted method.  If you don't want yet another data structure, you can always pick [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search).  If you have uniformly distributed numbers [interpolation search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) is probably the most effective method (best average performance).

Comment: Under what circumstances would Radix Sort have O(n^2) performance? Radix sort for fixed size integers is O(n) and for a reasonable implementation the complexity should not be affected by the distribution of the input.

Comment: Interestingly, an in-place binary radix sort on fixed-width integers is quite like quicksort (they're both repeated partitioning), but the pivots are fixed values whose sequence is determined in advance, instead of being elements of the array. And of course it dispenses with the book-keeping that quicksort needs to track what sub-section of the array is being partitioned. It'd be fun to see the results, but I didn't mention radix sort (or counting sorts) in my answer because the number of elements (2000) is so small that I don't expect their benefits to really kick in.

Comment: +1 for interpolation search, though. As you say, on uniform data it should beat binary search pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Standard sorting algorithms, as well as standard nearly anything, are very good **general purpose** solution. If you know nothing about your data, if it truly consists of "random unique integers", then you might as well go with one of the standard implementations.

On the other hand, most programming problems appear in a context that tells something about data, and the additional info usually leads to more efficient problem-specific solutions.

For example, does your data appear all at once or in chunks? If it comes piecemeal you may speed things up by interleaving incremental sorting, such as dual-pivot quicksort, with data acquisition.

Answer (score 0):

Since the domain of your numbers is so small, you can create an array of 65000 entries, set the index of the numbers you see to one, and then collect all numbers that are set to one as your sorted array. This will be exactly 67000 (assuming initialization of array is without cost) iterations in total.

Since the lists contain 2000 entries, `O(n*log(n))` will probably be faster. I can think of no other O(n) algorithm for this, so I suppose you are better off with a general purpose algorithm.